# MAMP, no records returned

Tags: php, mysql, mamp

I'm opening up a project from last year and figured I'd try MAMP on the new computer, seemed kinda cool.

Looks like it's all running, PHP works, and I rebuilt the database in phpMyAdmin.

After adding some test data to the tables, I made a simple test (see files below), but I couldn't retrieve anything from the database.

When I load test-basic.php it says "Connected to db. Selected database. Found Nothing =("

But I tested the string in phpMyAdmin (for the 'likeiwassaying' database) and it returned the results

I feel sooooo close (and have been banging my head on this for *hours*). Am I missing something right under my nose?

Any troubleshooting suggestions appreciated,

Justin

config.php

```
<?php
    $dbhost = 'localhost';
    $dbuser = 'root';
    $dbpassword = 'testpassword';
    $dbdatabase = 'likeiwassaying';
    $config_sitename = 'Cully Mail';    
    $config_author = 'jk';
    $config_basedir = 'http://localhost:8888/cullymail/';

    $db = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpassword);
    if (!$db) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    } else {
        echo 'Connected to db. ';
    }

    $db_selected = mysql_select_db($dbdatabase, $db);
    if (!$db_selected) {
        die ('Can\'t use: ' . mysql_error());
    } else {
        echo 'Selected database. ';
    }

    mysql_close($db);       

?>
```

test-basic.php

```
    require("config.php");

    function test() {
        $q = 'SELECT * FROM contacts;';

        $result = mysql_query($q);
        $numrows = mysql_num_rows($result);


        //If it is found (if any row comes back)...
        if($numrows == 0) {
            echo "Found nothing =(";
        } else {
            echo "found something";
        }

    }

    test();

?>
```

Comment: If something feels off about your MySQL queries, you can always die with the error message: `mysql_query($q) or die(mysql_error());` to see what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're closing your database connection before executing your function `test()`.  You close the connection at the end of `config.php`, meaning that by the time the function is defined in `test-basic.php` the db connection already no longer exists and further queries will fail.

You don't usually need to call `mysql_close()` explicitly, unless you have a need to regain memory resources early.  PHP will close down the connection when the script completes.

```
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($dbdatabase, $db);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Can\'t use: ' . mysql_error());
} else {
    echo 'Selected database. ';
}

// Everything is good so far. you're ready to execute queries, but...

// Don't do this!!!
mysql_close($db);
```

Comment: So, I just checked older versions of the file, and apparently that line must have crept in there in some of my troubleshooting. Thanks for the basic answer -- haven't done PHP in a while, but really want to revive this project. Big help!